# Commit changes to parent repository without commiting submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-push

I have a git repository say 'starter kit' and another git repository inside it.
After I make changes to submodule I want to push it to 'starter kit' and do nothing to submodule. How can I get this. Git wont allow me to do this. It says error: exit code 1 received when I try to commit.

Steps I followed.

```
~ git clone <starter-kit-git-url>
~ cd app/themes/
~ git clone <submodule-git-url>
~ cd ../.. (go back to root folder)
~ git submodule add <submodule-git-url> app/themes/submodule/
Adding existing repo at 'site/web/app/themes/submodule' to the index
```

made changes to a file in submodule.

```
~git status
    modified:   site/web/app/themes/submodule (modified content)

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

.gitmodules

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now I am unable to commit the submodule/ to parent repository ie 'starter kit' How to commit the changes to my repository only? When I try to commit them using github desktop it says 
"commit failed - exit code 1 received"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git submodule add` clones the submodule for you, you don't have to `git clone` the submodule before. After that, the first thing you should do is commit the adding of the submodule to your parent repository (`starter-kit`); the commit will add the .gitmodules file and the submodule directory to your repository.

Then, after you made changes in the submodule, you have to commit them inside the submodule, and after that have to commit the changes in the parent repository, since the commit the parent repository is pointing to has changed. You need to commit in both repositories every time you do a relevant change in the submodule.

It's unclear what you mean by

> Now I am unable to commit the submodule/ to parent repository

If my rather general explanation did not fix your issue, please elaborate further on what excactly you tried to commit in your parent repository.

Comment: your answered cleared my confusion. I tried to commit the parent repository without committing the submodule. My problem was I am not authorized to make commit or push the code to submodule. So I created another repository in github and changed the submodule to point that one. then I made commits to the submodule

Comment: What should we do if we actually do want to "overlay" changes by only comitting the path on the parent?